# Does SharePoint 2010 support Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0?

Tags: workflow

I've been reading that SharePoint 2010 does not support [Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489441%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (WF4). Is it true???

If yes, does that mean we cannot design WF4 workflows in VS2010 and use them in SP2010?
Or is it feasible? Will it be supported in a SharePoint service pack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 is based on .net 3.5, so no WF4.

Shame, but we'l have to live with it until the next version.